# Rectangle spinner with rounded corners

Tags: css, css-animations, loader

I am trying to make loader which will look like this on

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/PicturElements/pen/ZOwkwv)

But I need to have rounded borders, and rectangle, not a box. So I will be able to place the logo of our company to the loader.

I tried to make one more layer, which will be making inline radius and to the wrapper, I set `border-radius` and `overflow: hidden`.

But, the animation looks horrible And isn't smooth.

Can you please help me, to make this animation better? Or did you create something similar?

**UPDATE CODE SASS**

I am still experimenting with that.

```
#logoLoader
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -125px;
  margin-top: -32px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms;
  transition: background-color 500ms;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  .logo-image-wrapper
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 150;
    img 
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
  .logo-inline-corner
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height: calc(100% - 6px);
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 130;
    margin: 3px;
  .logo-background
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
  .loader
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #8dc63f;
    z-index: 125;

@keyframes slide1
  0%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  50%
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    margin-left: 0;
  99%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  100%
    margin-left: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;

@keyframes slide2
  0%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  50%
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    margin-top: 0;
  99%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  100%
    margin-top: 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;

@keyframes slide3
  0%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  50%
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    margin-right: 0;
  99%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  100%
    margin-right: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;

@keyframes slide4
  0%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  50%
    height: calc(100% - 2px); 
    margin-bottom: 0;
  99%
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  100%
    margin-bottom: 100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="logoLoader" style="display: none;">
      <div class="c4w-logo">
        <img src="images/c4w-logo-loader.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="logo-inline-corner"></div>
      <div class="loader" style="left:2px; top:0; height:2px; width:0; animation:slide1 1s linear forwards infinite" ></div>
      <div class="loader" style="right:0; top:2px; width:2px; height:0; animation:slide2 1s linear forwards infinite; animation-delay:0.5s"></div>
      <div class="loader" style="right:2px; bottom:0; height:2px; width:0; animation:slide3 1s linear forwards infinite"></div>
      <div class="loader" style="left:0; bottom:2px; width:2px; height:0; animation:slide4 1sl inear forwards infinite; animation-delay:0.5s"></div>
      <div class="logo-background"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: please include your version of code.

Comment: Updated HTML and CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG would be the more suitable here. Simply adjust the value of width/height and stroke properties:

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: visible;
}

svg>rect {
  stroke:purple;
  fill:transparent;
  stroke-dasharray: 130, 150;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 280;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="5" y="5" height="100%" width="100%"  rx="20" ry="20" stroke-width="10"/>
</svg>
```

But it can also be done with CSS. Here is an idea without transparency where the trick is to rotate an element that will cover only the borders and where we will apply `clip-path`:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.box:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-50%;
  left:-50%;
  right:-50%;
  bottom:-50%;
  background:blue;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 100%,100% 0, 100% 100%);
  animation:rotate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  50% {
    transform:rotate(90deg) scaleX(0.5) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

To understand the trick, remove the overflow and change some coloration:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:50px;
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  border-radius:10px;
}
.box:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-50%;
  left:-50%;
  right:-50%;
  bottom:-50%;
  background:blue;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,0 100%,100% 0, 100% 100%);
  animation:rotate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  50% {
    transform:rotate(90deg) scaleX(0.5) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

It can also be done without `clip-path` and a simple rectangle:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.box:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-100%;
  left:30%;
  right:30%;
  bottom:-100%;
  background:blue;
  animation:rotate 1s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  50% {
    transform:rotate(90deg) scaleX(0.5) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: It is very nice, thanks. I think that's enough. Very nice. Maybe I must learn more about SVG.

Comment: @Symorp i also added anther CSS idea ;)

Comment: Wow, thats awesome. But I more like the first solution :-), because with CSS there are changing angles at the end. But awesome work ;-) many thanks